# Replace and display a new page after value getting selected from dropdown in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, servlets

I have a dashboard where I have multiple drop down values, one of the drop-down have values which when get selected and a submit button is clicked it replaces the existing page design into a new page design.

Can anyone please shed some guidance how can I achieve that using JSP and servlets?

All I can think of is doing it using JavaScript and open a new window, but how can I do that in the same frame or `<div>` of the existing page?

> Also I need to keep the existing design by default before making an
>   attempt to switch the page.

Any help or valuable comments would be really great!

Comment: You can put all code in div and just refresh the div as change event occurs on the select. see these [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16874668/1031945) [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18490026/1031945)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showlevel1() {
        var l1 = document.getElementById('level1_category');
        l1.style.display = 'block';
        var l2 = document.getElementById('level2_category');
        l2.style.display = 'none';
    }

    function showlevel2() {
        var l2 = document.getElementById('level2_category');
        l2.style.display = 'block';
        var l1 = document.getElementById('level1_category');
        l1.style.display = 'none';

    }
    function categorySelectHandler(select) {

        if (select.value == '1') {

            var l1 = document.getElementById('level1_category');
            l1.style.display = 'none';
            var l2 = document.getElementById('level2_category');
            l2.style.display = 'none';

        } else if (select.value == '2') {
            showlevel1();
        } else if (select.value == '3') {
            showlevel2();
        }


    }
</script>


<html>
<select id="select_level" onchange="categorySelectHandler(this)">
      <option value="1">Create at level 1</option>
      <option value="2">Create at level 2</option>
      <option value="3">Create at level 3</option>
</select>


<div id="level1_category"  style="display:none;">

//   # Your Code Here

</div>

<div id="level2_category"  style="display:none;">

//   # Your Code Here

</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Dipak, it did work, I have one quick question, if I need to show level1_category div's design from the beginning by default, how do you suggest, I would achieve that?

Comment: I got that by setting display:block proprety in the default '<div>' i needed :) Thanks

Comment: @akiiddweeber wel Come