# Reloading content of a div element in a tab content

Tags: jquery, html, tabs, refresh

I have defined 2 tabs and in e.g "#tabs-2" I have A "div" element () that I want to refresh when I click on tab-2. and I only need to refresh that div not the whole page.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1" id="tabs-1">first</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2"  id="tabs-2">second</a></li>

        </ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
<p>tab-1 content</p>
</div>

<div id="tabs-2">
<html>
    <head>
    </head> 

        <body>
          **<div class="container-fluid"></div>**
        </body>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help you: [Refresh a div with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874668/refresh-a-div-with-jquery)

Another solution are using partial views for every tab like this

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="action-tab1" href="#tabs-1">My TAB 1</a></li>
        <li><a id="action-tab2" href="#tabs-2">My TAB 2</a></li>
        <li><a id="action-tab3" href="#tabs-3">My TAB 3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1">
        @Html.Partial("_MyPartialView1")
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        @Html.Partial("_MyPartialView2")
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        @Html.Partial("_MyPartialView3")
    </div>
</div>
<script>
  $(function() {
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
   $("#tabs-2").click(function()
   {
      // DO YOUR REFRESH WORK HERE
   });
 });
</script>
```